# How to get row labels on Angular Material Table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I was wondering if it's possible to add a left-sided column such that it contains all of the row labels used to define [angular material tables](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

In other words, something like this:

```
*******************************************
*rowlabel * some val * some val * some val
*******************************************
*rowlabel * some val * some val * some val
*******************************************
*rowlabel * some val * some val * some val
*******************************************
*rowlabel * some val * some val * some val
*******************************************
```

In other words, the columns represent the results of formulas and the labels would show how the numbers are calculated.

I don't see anywhere in the documentation as to how you would accomplish this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're asking for? Maybe attach an image instead of code? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just add those "labels" as row data.

Comment: Not possible for the tens of thousands of responses I'll be dealing with.

Comment: So how do you want to do that if not programmatically? Thought its all about programing here.

Comment: Or, you can just create labels once, store them and add them on the fly to  the table data model. If you realy think that just adding extra column with fixed values will affect performance in a way that you will ever notice - think again. O(1). Good luck

Comment: @Antoniossss Maybe add a code example to your answer how to do this? Otherwise this looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Please, could you add some example and explanation? I have no doubts your solution can work, but you need to share it with us (if possible, with code)